# How do I implement this Pseudocode?

Tags: c++, hashmap, pseudocode

I am trying to write a function to hash strings into integers so I can use strings as keys in my hash map. I'm required to use the pseudocode written below, but I still can't get it to work without errors.
The program is to enter a German word (as key) and return it's English translation (as value).

The pseudocode:

```
Parameters : natural numbers i, h = 0; Field s
 for i = 0 to i <length_of (s)
    h = (h * 128 + s [i]) mod M;
Result : h.
```

My code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define M 661
using namespace std;

struct entry {
    string key_de, val_en;
};

int HASH(int i, int h = 0, struct entry ex_array[])
{
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(ex_array) / sizeof(ex_array[0]); i++)
    {
        h = (h * 128) + ex_array[i] % m;
    }
    return h;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: In the "int HASH" I'm getting default argument not at end of parameter list.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: @OmarBaz Seems like the error you're getting is pretty descriptive of what is wrong.

Comment: `h` must be the last parameter. Also, `sizeof(ex_array)` is not going to work well.

Comment: `struct entry ex_array[]` in `c++` you don't need the `struct`. This is one difference between `c` and `c++`

Comment: Thank you, that solved the HASH problem but now I'm getting an error with the mod operator: no operator "%" matches these operands.  Operand types are entry % int.

Comment: Pass the size of the array as a parameter. You can't do `sizeof(ex_array) / sizeof(ex_array[0])`

Comment: It does not make sense to use the `%` operator with a struct.

Comment: Perhaps the `m` in `h = (h * 128) + ex_array[i] % m;` is really the `M` from `#define M 661`? Otherwise the former is undefined and the later is unused.

Comment: The reason `sizeof(ex_array) / sizeof(ex_array[0])` does not work: `ex_array` [decayed to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), so `sizeof(ex_array)` will always be the size of a pointer, not the size of the array used as the argument.

Comment: Since it's tagged C++, here is the obligatory recommendation to use vectors: Use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of C-style arrays to make your life easier.

Comment: or `std::array` if the array size is fixed at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a way you could implement that

```
#include <string>
#define M 661

int Hash(std::string s, int h = 0){
   for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length(); i++)
      h = (h * 128 + s [i]) % M;
   return h;
}
```

I have one note though. In the pseudo code you provided i'm not so sure that the "parameters" provided are talking about actual function parameters because it seems a little strange to pass in 'i' since you immediately set it to to 0 (for i = 0 ...). But if you do need to pass 'i' in then you can just add it to the beginning of the argument list and remove the 'int' from inside the for loop.

Then you can use this function to get the hash value of the German word.

Here's an example of how to use it

```
string arr[M]; //assuming M is size of array
std::string germanWord{"german"}; //some German word
std::string englishWord{"english"} //same word but in English
arr[Hash(germanWord)] = englishWord //adding new English word to the array
string s = arr[Hash(germanWord)] // accessing that word from the array
```

there are other things you might have to think about if you are going to make an actual hash map (Like how you deal with collisions) but this is enough if you just want to implement that pseudo code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much foe your help, this is exactly what I wanted.